# How to get primary category from DB tables in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

With Yoast SEO comes a functionality to set primary category among more than one category selection.
I am writing a piece of code where I need to fetch the primary category using the word-press DB tables.
I am unable to identify a way to query the DB to get only the primary category and not any other category associated with the post.

I am using wordpress version 4.5.3 with Yoast SEO installed.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out.
The primary category as is a feature of the Yoast SEO plugin is available in **wp_postmeta** table. 
Each post's primary category is set against **meta_key** value
"**_yoast_wpseo_primary_category**"
with **meta_value** having the **term_id** from the **wp_terms** table for the primary category.

Answer (score 0):

this query show for posts:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts t1 
INNER join `wp_postmeta`t2 
on t1.ID = t2.post_id
where meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category'
```

this query show primary category for products:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts t1 
INNER join `wp_postmeta`t2 
on t1.ID = t2.post_id
where meta_key = '_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat'
```

pay attention that `meta_key` value on above have different.